# jQuery animate div height after dynamic loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I load page via AJAX and its content is represented as a string. After that I want to animate container's height if the content is bigger than actual container's height. But, `_height` is 0. Why ?

```
function adjustMainContainerHeight() {
    var _height = $('div.content').wrapInner('<div>').outerHeight();

    $("div.main").animate({ height: _height  }, 600);
}

function prepareResult(data) { //data is HTML string returned by server
    $('div.content').html(data);
    adjustMainContainerHeight();
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `wrapInner`?

Comment: is your script at the bottom of you page? Tryd it with $( document ).ready() (to make sure the div is loaded allready)

Comment: AJAX request is being invoked inside $(document).ready(function () {}), those two functions are outside $(document).ready(function () {})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** heres a fiddle with a working animation for the container (or other div) of a loaded (simulation) content:

http://jsfiddle.net/sK6LN/

```
function adjustMainContainerHeight(_height) {

    $("div.main").animate({ height: _height  }, 600);
}

function prepareResult(data) { //data is HTML string returned by server
    $('div.content').html(data);
    adjustMainContainerHeight($('div.content').height());
}

$(function(){
    $('div.main').height(0);
    prepareResult('<p>foo</p><p>bar</p><p>foo</p><p>bar</p>');
});
```

Comment: no, it returns me the div.content height, but I see that the loaded HTML's height is much more higher than the div.content's height

Comment: for me, $('div.content').html(data); causes height jump and adjustMainContainerHeight causes nothing of course

Comment: there are only 2 things which couse these jumps: 1) the data is not loaded in a callback function - 2) you have some padding/margin issues with the .height() function. debug it.

Comment: the solution was, after $('div.content').html(data); get the first div inside it and get it's height. Now it's working, thanks